# Cannot Cannot read property from protractor-image-comparison

Tags: javascript, angular, configuration, protractor, automated-tests

I'm new to frontend world, I would like to write some test using protractor-image-comparison. I followed installation instructions from https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-image-comparison. Also I make configuration according to this page.
When I try to use functions form this lib I get following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkFullPageScreen' of undefined". I'm getting a warrning in protractor.conf.js in

```
const protractorImageComparison = require('protractor-image-comparison');
```

> "Could not find a declaration file for module
>   'protractor-image-comparison'.
>   '/home/rafa/repos/example/src/example/node_modules/protractor-image-comparison/index.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install
>   @types/protractor-image-comparison` if it exists or add a new
>   declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module
>   'protractor-image-comparison';`"

So I did, I made simple *.d.ts file with  `declare module protractor-image-comparison' in it, but it didn't solve the problem just the warning disappear. It's propably the config issue, but I can't handle it or maybe I made wrong declaration. This is my config file :

// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

```
const reporter = require("cucumber-html-reporter");
const path = require("path");

const jsonReports = path.join(process.cwd(), "/reports/json");
const htmlReports = path.join(process.cwd(), "/reports/html");
const targetJson = jsonReports + "/cucumber_report.json";



const cucumberReporterOptions = {
  jsonFile: targetJson,
  output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
  reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
  theme: "bootstrap",
};

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

  restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,

  //SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

  specs: [
    './e2e/**/login.feature'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },


  directConnect: true,

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',

  framework: 'custom',

  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

  cucumberOpts: {
    format: "json:" + targetJson,
    require: ['./e2e/steps/*.ts', "./e2e/timeout.ts"], 
  },

  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,

  onPrepare: () => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    const protractorImageComparison = require('protractor-image-comparison');
    browser.protractorImageComparison = new protractorImageComparison(
      {
                baselineFolder: "report/screens/baseline",
                screenshotPath: "report/screens/actual"
      }
    );
  },

  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e'
    });
  },

  onComplete: () => {
    reporter.generate(cucumberReporterOptions);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. The reason why I was getting this TypeError is that I lunched few test scenarios and onPrepare was lunched only in the begining. I move config of protractor-image-comparison to cucumber befor hook and everything works fine now.